# Trying to run a bash script with source from another script running as source

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that will eventually call another bash script. Each script must be run with "source". For simplicity's sake, I've summarized the problem points below

**script1.sh**:

```
source script2.sh
```

**script2.sh**:

```
export someVar=something
```

Run everything with:

```
source script1.sh arg1 arg2
```

The issue is when *script2.sh* is run from *script1.sh*, the arguments are also copied, so *script2.sh* is actually run as:

```
source script2.sh arg1 arg2
```

*script2.sh* fails because those arguments are provided. Is there any way that I can run script2 from script1 without passing those *args*? Running script2 without the source command is not an option, unless there is another way for it to be run and let the variables persist. I also can not modify script2 in any way.

Comment: If you no longer need those arguments, you could call `shift 2` in `script1` before sourcing `script2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the positional parameters using `set --` when you're done with them:

**script1.sh**:

```
echo "Number of parameters before: $#"
set --
echo "Number of parameters after : $#"
source script2.sh
```

**script2.sh**:

```
echo "script2.sh received $# parameters"
```

Now `script1.sh foo bar` will print

```
Number of parameters before: 2
Number of parameters after : 0
script2.sh received 0 parameters
```